# Files disappear when commit branches in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, branch

I have a very serious problem, and really need some help.
I have been working on a Android project using Eclipse for a month, and 2 weeks ago, I decided to make some major changes, so I did a branch on git (say design 1). Everything was fine, and I have been working on the new branch.

Today, I wanted to make another major change, so I added the files into version control, committed, and add another branch (say design 2), then I realised all the files along with my design 1 branch disappeared. And I couldn't find them anyway!!! 
What actually happened?!

Is there anyway to retrieve those files. I tried to unzip the apk file from bin, but it contain no source code.

Please help me!!

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you were doing. Are you saying you created a branch, worked on it for a couple of weeks before adding any files and committing? Care to show us the commands you use in your workflow,  such as branching and committing changes. What exactly did you do?

Comment: Solved... My old branch wasn't showing in Eclipse. So I used git in command line, went to the directory, used 'git branch' and saw my old branch, then use 'git checkout *branch' to restore my old branch. Almost peed my pants...